# Angular 4.0.3: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined

Tags: angular, angular-cli

After upgrading my `Angular 4.0.2` application to `Angular 4.0.3`, I get the following error in the Chrome console:

```
zone.js:1265 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
    at XMLHttpRequest.desc.get [as ontimeout] (zone.js:1265)
    at XHRLocalObject.AbstractXHRObject._cleanup (abstract-xhr.js:149)
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (abstract-xhr.js:125)
    at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn (zone.js:1230)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:398)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:165)
    at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js:460)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Temporarily downgrade `zone.js`:

```
    npm install zone.js@0.8.7 --save
```

**Details:**

The `zone.js 0.8.8` dependency is the root cause of the error, so fix the version at `0.8.7` until this is fixed which should happen when [zone#747](https://github.com/angular/zone.js/pull/747) lands.